# Xgboost package on mac

Tags: python, pip, xgboost

I am trying to use Xgboost but facing problems in installation.
i am using mac and I use python notebook jupyter for the same. I opened the command line and used `pip install xgboost` and it got installed successfully but when I try to use it in my code by writing `import xgboost as xg` then I get  `ImportError: No module named xgboost`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: check version of python and version of pip used match (very common problem) for pip do `pip --version` and for python run `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: if they don't match you can use `pip3` / `pip2` / `pip2.7` / `pip3.5` etc. to install the package for a specific version of python on your computer.

Comment: I tried that. python is 2.7 and pip is pip 8.1.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: can you import it when running python from terminal? if so then this probably needs the `ipython-notebook` tag.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ipython-notebook tag?

Comment: sorry, mixing up ipython-notebook and notebook jupyter.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? What are the results from running `which python`, `which ipython`, and `which pip` (are they all the same)? If they are NOT the same, this is what the problem is. Can you `import xgboost` from the python shell, rather than the ipython notebook?

Comment: No, I am not using virtual environment. Which python yields /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python  . Which pip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip   and which ipython yields  /Users/PrashantMudgal/anaconda/bin/ipython

Comment: I am able to import xgboost from python shell

Answer (score 0):

It may come from the fact that you have two (or more) python environments. A hacky solution is to install it within Jupyter Notebook (note the '!'):

```
!pip install xgboost
```